# Relation in Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-rest-framework

I am using `serializers.GeoFeatureModelSerializer` to serialize Model. I have a queryset

that is creating `Left Outer Join`. I want to serialize related Model fields

Here is my Model

```
class LookupTiming(models.Model):
    day = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    time_1 = models.TimeField()
    time_2 = models.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'lookup_timing'

class Streets(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    geometry = models.GeometryField(null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'streets'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name


class StreetTimings(models.Model):
    street= models.ForeignKey(Streets)
    lookuptiming = models.ForeignKey(LookupTiming)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'street_timings'
```

> queryset =
>   Streets.objects.filter(streettimings_*lookuptiming*_isnull=True)

Serializer Class

```
class StreetSerializer(gis_serializer.GeoFeatureModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Streets
        geo_field = "geometry"
        id_field = False
        fields = ('id', 'streettimings__lookuptiming__day', other fields)
```

**Updated**

I want to show following fields on response

```
Streets (id)

LookupTiming (day)
```

I want output like this query simple is that

```
SELECT "streets"."id", "lookuptiming"."day" FROM "streets"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "streettimings" ON ( "streets"."id" = "streettimings"."street_id" ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "lookuptiming" ON ( "streettimings"."lookuptiming_id" = "lookuptiming"."id" )
```

How can i do this?

Thank you

Comment: can you please add how will the final serialized data look like. Also what is this street_id? Is it the ID of the street which is being serialized?

Comment: i have updated question please check